# Get all occurrence of specific day in a month

Tags: php

Suppose i have a month June 2014. Now i want to get dates of all Mondays in June month.

like Monday is coming on following days so answer will be like following

```
2014-06-02
2014-06-09
2014-06-16
2014-06-23
2014-06-30
```

please do not give be static solution only for June. I need dynamic solution for every month and purely in PHP.

Comment: it's only for a day of the week or another element?

Comment: Did you try the trivial way? (`$a = new \DateTime("first monday of 2014-06");` then adding +7 days while it's the same month)

Comment: @ekans Yes it is only for day of the week

Comment: somehow this feel like an homework assignment to me. What have you tried so far? for directions, take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: you could take calendar and make a looooong array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
<?php
$startDate = "2014-06-01";
$endDate = "2014-06-30";

$startDate = strtotime($startDate);
$endDate = strtotime($endDate);

for($i = strtotime('Monday', $startDate); $i <= $endDate; $i = strtotime('+1 week', $i))
    echo date('l Y-m-d', $i).PHP_EOL;
```

**DEMO:**

http://3v4l.org/n4ULA

Comment: Thanks a lot for your precious time. It works for me

Answer (score 1):

Try to create an array with all your date with day on key (with variable $day and $date):

```
$array = array("Monday" => "2014-06-02", "Tuesday" => "2014-06-03", "Wednesday" => "2014-06-04");
```

You create a loop to reach all the result :

```
foreach($array as $key => $value {
    if($key == "Monday")
       echo $value;
}
```

Comment: definitely best solution :D, if you make it this way you get A+, 100%

Answer (score -1):

Using the above, I created this so you can use variables to define the month, year, and selected weekday.

```
$month = "6";
$year = "2022";
$weekday = "Tuesday";

$d=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$month,$year);
$first_date_of_month = $year."-".$month."-01";
$last_date_of_month = $year."-".$month."-".$d;

$startDate = strtotime($first_date_of_month);
$endDate = strtotime($last_date_of_month);

for($i = strtotime($weekday, $startDate); $i <= $endDate; $i = strtotime('+1 week', $i))
    echo "<br />". date('l Y-m-d', $i).PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).