# Get n occurrences of a weekday

Tags: php

I need 4 occurrence of Friday with date. Start date from 2014-05-25

Following will be the answer in this case.

```
2014-05-30
2014-06-06
2014-06-13
2014-06-20
```

There can be n occurrence of specific weekday and i need solution purely in PHP not in mysql

Comment: "*please do not give me static solution.*" — That's not how the site works. We don't write code for you, we only help you write it. Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Are the dates dateTime objects or timestamps or ..?

Comment: @Naruto I have only start date and from that start date i have to find n occurrence of weekday. date format should be like year-month-date

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get all occurrence of specific day in a month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469816/get-all-occurrence-of-specific-day-in-a-month)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

You can do something like:

```
strtotime("+1 week", timestamp);
```

Where `timestamp` is the UNIX timestamp for the start date. You can replace 1 with a variable, and by using a loop you can write a generic function.

Hope this helps.

Edit #1:

Also, you can recur to strtotime() to generate your timestamp:

```
strtotime("+1 week", strtotime('2014-05-30'));
```

A possible whole solution would be (untested code):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i ++) {
   strtotime("+" . $i . " week", strtotime('2014-04-25'));
}
```

Comment: You can still use the strtotime() to do that. Please refer to the documentation in the first link of the answer.

Comment: Also what you're asking may be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784484/how-to-find-nearest-day-of-week-in-php

Comment: I'm not asking anything, the guy who asked the question did.. :)

Comment: Note that I answered your exact question. The Friday occurence part you're looking for is in the posted stackoverflow link.