# How to determine if day of week is 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc occurrence in a month?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I need to determine what day of the week a given date is, and what occurrence of that day of week it is in the given date's month.

The 3rd Sunday in January, 2017 is the 15th. I know this by looking at a calendar. But given I only know the exact date, how can I figure out it's the 3rd Sunday programmatically?

Determining the actually day of week is pretty easy by loading the date into PHP and formatting it to output the day:

```
$day_of_week = date('l', $timestamp);
```

It's the other part I can't quite figure out.

Comment: this might be a useful resource. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469816/get-all-occurrence-of-specific-day-in-a-month If you know your day, and you can get all the occurences of the day in the month, you can figure out which occurence is yours.

Comment: How many times can you subtract a full week from the 15th? 15 minus 7 is 8, 8 minus 7 is 1. Therefor, there have been two Sundays before the 15th, so 3 in all.

Comment: Blatantly piggybacking on @CBroe's comment, something like `$day = 20; $dayCount = ceil($day / 7); // 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this which works out the *current* day or you could set any other valid timestamp to $timestamp:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$timestamp = time();
$day_of_week = date('l', $timestamp);
$day_of_the_month = date('j', $timestamp);
$occurence = ceil($day_of_the_month / 7);
$suffix = 'th';

if($occurence == 3){
  $suffix = 'rd';
} else if($occurence == 2){
  $suffix = 'nd';
} else if($occurence == 1){
  $suffix = 'st';
}

print 'It is the '.$occurence.$suffix.' '.$day_of_week.' of this month';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no better way than just looping throught the full month and counting which on them is sunday. I would also recommend you to use a library like Carbon ([Carbon oficial docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/))

So, your code should be doing:

1. You collect you date

```html
$dt = Carbon::createFromDate(2012, 10, 6);
```

2. A Carbon date object has a property called "dayOfWeek", so no more hassle here

```html
if ($dt->dayOfWeek === Carbon::SATURDAY) {
    
}
```

3. @CBroe is actually better. You can just just divide by 7 your week number (no decimals) and add 1 to the result, that's the ocurrence.

PD: Sorry, I got no PHP editor nor access to my development PC